# Can 'It does “to” subject' be used in this context?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> Wealth does not make you happy, but it does “to” me.

I don’t want to repeat the phrase “make subject happy” as seen below, so can I say “it does to me”?

> Wealth does not make you happy, but it does make me happy

Comment: Wealth does not make you happy but it does me. No to. Versus: It makes no difference **to me** but does **to you**.